# Passing an unmanaged C++ structure by reference to a managed C++ method causes an access violation when the structure is referenced

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed, managed-c++

I'm trying to pass this structure:

```
#pragma unmanaged
typedef struct
{
   void* data;
   unsigned nlen;
   unsigned int type; 
} PARAMETER;
```

To this class static method:

```
#pragma managed
private class __gc GlobalFunctions
{
   static void WriteField(Object* object, PARAMTER& par, unsigned dec)
   {
       switch (par.type)
       {
          ....
       }
   }
};
```

From this function:

```
public class __gc WorkerClass
{
   void SetValueAt(long index, Object* value)
   {
      PARAMETER aux;
      aux.type = 3;
      GlobalFunctions::WriteField(value, aux, 0);
   }
};
```

On a 64-bit system, I get an access violation saying that the address '0x000c' cannot be read.

Now, on a 64-bit system, the dereference of par.type would be address of 0x0c if the reference of par was a null pointer. Except par is on the stack - I'm not passing a null pointer into WriteField, but I seem to be getting one out.

Now, in Managed C++, when calling from one managed class instance method to another static method, is the fact that I'm passing an *unmanaged* structure by reference vulnerable to some sort of marshalling issue?

Is there any web documentation explaining how unmanaged structures are treated by managed code?

Answer (score 0):

Have the managed and the un-managed code be explicitly compiled as managed/un-managed. If the managed and un-managed code is mixed in the same file the pragma managed and pragma unmanaged needs to be used. Also keep that in mind when you use include files.